# Mapping JSON Object in typescript

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, typescript, next.js

this is my JSOn Object.

```
export const customImage = [
  {
    status: false,
    image: null,
    price: 10,
  },
  {
    status: false,
    image: null,
    price: 20,
  },
];
```

I have imported it in the code below I above Array should be imported to that

```
"use client";
import Button from "@/app/components/Button";
import CustomImageInput from "@/app/components/inputs/CustomImageInput";
import PackageButton from "@/app/components/inputs/PackageButton";
import ProductImage from "@/app/components/products/ProductImage";
import SetQuantity from "@/app/components/products/SetQuantity";
import TypeImage from "@/app/components/products/setTypeImage";
import SetColor from "@/app/components/products/setColor";
import SetType from "@/app/components/products/setType";
import { useCart } from "@/hooks/useCart";
import { customImage } from "@/utils/customImage";
import { formatPrice } from "@/utils/formatprice";
import { Rating } from "@mui/material";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { MdCheckCircle } from "react-icons/md";

interface ProductDetailsProps {
  product: any;
}

export type CartProductType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  category: string;
  brand: string;
  selectedImg: SelectedImgType;
  selectedProduct: SelectedProductType;
  quantity: number;
  selectedPackage: SelectedPackageType;
  price: number;
  //file: any;
  selectedCustomImage: SelectedCustomImageType[];
  //selectedCustomImage: String;
};
// customImagePrice: number;

export type SelectedImgType = {
  color: string;
  colorCode: string;
  image: string;
};

export type SelectedProductType = {
  type: string;
  typeCode: string;
  typePrice: number;
  image: string;
};

export type SelectedPackageType = {
  packaging: string;
  price: number;
  image: string;
};

export type SelectedCustomImageType = {
  status: boolean;
  image: string | null;
  price: number;
};

export type CustomImage = {
  status: boolean;
  image: File | null;
  price: number;
};

const Horizontal = () => {
  return <hr className="w-[30% my-2]" />;
};

const ProductDetails: React.FC<ProductDetailsProps> = ({ product }) => {
  //const { cartProducts, handleClearCart, cartTotalAmount } = useCart();

  const router = useRouter();

  const { handleAddProductToCart, cartProducts } = useCart();

  const [isProductInCart, setIsProductInCart] = useState(false);

  const [cartProduct, setCartProduct] = useState<CartProductType>({
    id: product.id,
    name: product.name,
    description: product.description,
    category: product.category,
    brand: product.brand,
    selectedImg: { ...product.images[0] },
    selectedProduct: { ...product.type[0] },
    quantity: 1,
    price: product.price,
    selectedPackage: { ...product.productPackages[0] },
    selectedCustomImage: <<<< I need to map this object as an array customImage>>>>,
  });
```

Here I want to map the selectedCustomImage below the imported customImage. How can I do that ??? Please help me map this array to selectedCustomImage (that must be mapped as selectedImg,selectedProduct, and selectedPackage)

Comment: Maybe with the [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  function?

Comment: is this what you are trying to achieve  selectedCustomImage.map((imageData, index)=> {} ?

Comment: `selectedCustomImage: typeof customImage[number]`